# why does void inside of promise.then not return undefined?

Tags: javascript, promise

My co-worker wrote structurally this kind of code:

`Promise.resolve(2).then(void console.log('3')).then(x => x + 2)`

Can someone explain why the `x` argument is not "undefined" in the last `then`

Comment: You're effectively calling `Promsise.resolve(2).then(undefined).then(x => x + 2)`.

Comment: still surprised stuffing "undefined" into then doesn't effectively cut the chain

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ### Syntax
>
> ```
> then(onFulfilled)
> then(onFulfilled, onRejected)
> ```
>
> #### Parameters
>
> `onFulfilled` (Optional)
> A Function asynchronously called if the `Promise` is fulfilled. This function has one parameter, the fulfillment value. **If it is not a function, it is internally replaced with an identity function (`(x) => x`) which simply passes the fulfillment value forward.**
>
> http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then

`void` produces such a "not a function", specifically `undefined`, so the `onFulfilled` function is implicitly replaced with `x => x`.